# predict_proba() method of Keras model does not exist

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, probability

I am trying to generate class scores by calling `predict_proba()` of Keras model, but it seems that this function does not exist! Is it deprecated because I see some examples in Google? I am using Keras 2.2.2.

Comment: Is your model a Sequential model or is it created using functional API?

Comment: @today it a `Keras.models.Model()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `predict_proba()` and `predict_classes()` methods [are not well-defined for models created using functional API](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2524#issuecomment-218590463) (i.e. `keras.models.Model()`). That's because the models created using functional API may have multiple output layers each with different configurations. Therefore predicting probabilities in this case is not meaningful, even if your model outputs probabilities. The method you referred to, as well as `predict_classes()`, is only defined for Sequential models (i.e. `keras.models.Sequential()`).

Comment: `That's because the models created using functional API may have multiple output layers each with different configurations` could explain more or give an example of model ? Could MaskRCNN be an example of such models

Comment: @BetterEnglish Take this as an example: a model that takes the image of a face and predicts its gender (i.e. one output layer with possibly binary crossentropy loss) as well as the its age (i.e. another output layer with linear activation function and mean squared error as loss). However, the important thing here is that no matter the model has one output layer or more than one output layers, if you have defined it using functional API, you can't access `predict_proba()`, `predict_classes()`, etc. methods.

Comment: I understand that if I define it using functional API, I can't access to predict_proba function. My question is why we can't define such function ? In your example, I think we can not do that because we have classification and regression outputs in the same time. I think it does not make sense to define predict_prob only on the classification layer.

Comment: @BetterEnglish "I think it does not make sense to define predict_prob only on the classification layer." I see your point that you might be able define posterior probability in case of a regression task but it might differ from task to task. And I guess that's why it is not supported in the first place. However, in case of a classification task actually the outputs of the model are directly probabilities (at least this is the presumption) and therefore [`model.predict()` is equivalent to `model.predict_proba()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/sequential.py#L231).